# How do you monitor a select tag?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm sure there is a very simple solution, I just don't know it...

I have a text box and a selector. The first option in the selection is custom, where they can input with the text box. If they select something else, the text box becomes disabled.

I'm guessing the solution will be to put an onclick to test the value, but is there another way?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `change` event, not the `click` event.

```
var select = document.getElementById('mySelect'),
    textbox = document.getElementById('myTextbox');

function onSelectChanged()
{
    console.log(select.selectedIndex);
    textbox.disabled = select.selectedIndex !== 0;
}

if (select.addEventListener)
{
    select.addEventListener('change', onSelectChanged, false);
}
else
{
    // !@#$ing IE support, of course
    select.attachEvent('onchange', onSelectChanged, false);
}
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/pJMWN/

Comment: ?? I'm REALLY new to all this. I'm having a bit of trouble understanding.

Comment: You'll want `...attachEvent("onchange"...` for IE because it doesn't use a "change" event.

Comment: Or just set the `onchange` attribute on the element itself.  Then you don't have to worry about that kind of browser-specific nonsense. `<select onchange="..." />` will work consistently in any modern browser.

Comment: With the `attachEvent` method, `this` doesn't give you a reference to the element in the handler. You'd need to do `select.selectedIndex === 0`, or you'd need to create a closure around the element and do `handler.call( el, event );`

Comment: @all thanks for the comments, I fouled that one up mightily. Fixed.

Answer (score 0):

dont think onclick will serve your purpose better use onchange event in the selection and check for the selected value not equal to custom and then enable/disable your text box...

Hope this helps you,,,,

Answer (score 0):

You would use an `onchange` listener on your `select` element.  I also recommend using an `onkeyup` listener because some browsers do not fire `onchange` events when the user changes the select-box value using the keyboard.  Here is some example code:

```
<select id="mySelect" name="name" onkeyup="this.onchange();" onchange="selectChanged(this);">
    <option value="-1">(custom value)</option>
    <option value="1">1</option>
    <option value="2">2</option>
</select>
<input type="text" id="customText" name="customOption" value="" />

<script>
    window.selectChanged = function(theSelect) {
        var textInput = document.getElementById("customText");
        if (theSelect.selectedIndex == 0) {
            textInput.disabled = undefined;
        }
        else {
            textInput.disabled = true;
            textInput.value = "";
        }
    };
</script>
```

Example:  http://jsfiddle.net/tB2Am/2/

Comment: if (theSelect.selectedIndex == 0)

Does this mean the first option because the indexing starts at 0?

Comment: @user828584 - Yes, `theSelect.selectedIndex == 0` is checking to see if the first option is currently selected.

Comment: I'm also having a bit of trouble understanding how this all works. 

onchange="selectChanged(this);"

That means that when it is changed, it will execute the selectChanged function with argument "this", right?

But then you wrote

window.selectChanged = function(theSelect) {

How does that define a function?

Comment: @user828584 - Yes, when the `select` is changed, it will call the `selectChanged()` function.  The code that goes `window.selectChanged = function(theSelect) { ...` is defining a property called `selectChanged` on the `window` object, and assigning a function to that property.  In JavaScript this is equivalent to declaring the function in the global namespace.  In essence, it gives you a function called "selectChanged" that can be invoked from anywhere.